# react-native-linkedin-sdk - Cannot read property 'configure' of undefined (LinkedInSessionManager.ios.js)

Tags: android, xcode, react-native, sdk, linkedin-api

I have followed all steps described [here](https://github.com/joonhocho/react-native-linkedin-sdk)

Here is props of my environment:

```
react 16.0.0-alpha.6
react-native 0.43.3
react-native-linkedin-sdk 0.0.4
XCode 8.3.2
```

The Xcode project compiles without issues but I receive an error msg when I invoke the JS code below that the function `configure` is undefined

Here is my test code:

```
const config = {
  clientID: '<my client id>',
  clientSecret: '<my secret>',
  state: '<my state hash>',
  scopes: 'r_basicprofile',
  redirectUri: '<my redirect URL>'
}
const LISDK = LinkedInSDK.configure(config)
```

The code snipped that causes the error is in `LinkedInSessionManager.ios.js`

```
...
const LinkedInSDK = {
  configure(config) {
    console.info('LINKEDIN SESSION MANAGER', RNLinkedInSessionManager)
    return RNLinkedInSessionManager.configure(config);
  },
  ...
};

module.exports = LinkedInSDK;
```

I added a console output to check whether I get a `RNLinkedInSessionManager` object but I get an `undefined`, which means the code of the **RNLinkedInSessionManager** project is not connected to react-native.

The file `RNLinkedInSessionManager.xcworkspace` has been successfully added to my XCode project folder under `/ios` but it seems there is no link to the library.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi did you find a solution. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm still fighting without success :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up using the `react-native-linkedin-sdk`.

Instead I successfully implemented this library [react-native-linkedin-login](https://github.com/jodybrewster/react-native-linkedin-login)

Nevertheless the library doesn't work without some modifications.

Here my findings:

**Android:**

I followed all steps [here](https://github.com/jodybrewster/react-native-linkedin-login/blob/master/md/android.guide.md) but I received the following error:

**Error:Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-linkedin-login.**

It turns out the path described in the above instructions is wrong. 
To solve the problem I updated the path in the `settings.gradle` file like that:

```
//project(':react-native-linkedin-login').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../../android')
project(':react-native-linkedin-login').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-linkedin-login/android')
```

After that I could successfully build the project.

**iOS:**

After completing all steps as described [here](https://github.com/jodybrewster/react-native-linkedin-login/blob/master/md/ios.guide.md) you will have a folder `RNLinkedinLogin` in your XCode project path.

Drop the **LinkedinLogin.m** file into the `Build Phases` -> `Compiled Sources`

Both files have the old import syntax  but since react native 0.40 and above the syntax has changed. You must edit these imports accordingly.

Changed the import in file `RNLinkedinLogin.m`

```
 // old syntax
 //#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"
 // new syntax
 #import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
```

and the import in file 'RNLinkedinLogin.h`

```
 //#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
 #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

Your project will now compile without errors.

Good luck,
Tom